# Customize UIDocumentPickerViewController NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I am trying to customize UIDocumentPickerViewController NavigationBar but am not able to change the appearance of the navigation bar of UIDocumentPickerViewController.

Only tintColor is getting changed. Everything else remains as it is.

In my app, there is an ImagePicker as well, that is able to inherit NavigationBar appearance changes which I have done in AppDelegate.

But the same doesn't work with UIDocumentPicker.

According to Apple documentation, UIImagePicker is a subclass of UINavigationController whereas UIDocumentPickerViewController is a subclass of UIViewController.

Let me know any more info is needed from my side to help understand it better.

Comment: What sort of customizations are you trying to make?  What changes don't work?  It doesn't look like `UIDocumentPickerViewController` offers any mechanism to access its component views so it doesn't look like it's designed to be customized.

Comment: Across my whole app, the navigation bar has the same color code which I have set through Navigation Bar Appearance. But same is not getting applied to UIDocumentPickerViewController Bar.